# Snowflake - Snowpipe - SNS - SQS Subscriptions - Pending confirmation

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As part of SNS configuration, I followed all the steps mentioned in the link https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#option-2-configuring-amazon-sns-to-automate-snowpipe-using-sqs-notifications. But still I don't see any message on SQS queue even though new file is dropped in S3 bucket. One thing I noticed that "Create subscriptions" steps are missing to add Snowflake SQS. I went ahead and added Snowflake SQS ARN in the subscription of the SNS topic but the status shows "Pending confirmation". I am not sure where we can approve this confirmation?? Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't get past `Pending confirmation` step since the SQS queues that receive the message with confirmation URL are inside Snowflake's AWS accounts.

What worked was subscribing the Snowflake SQS queues directly to the [S3 bucket events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html) in our account (skipping the SNS hop). No confirmation required.